# There is some issue while doing dotnetnuke(6.2) project live

Tags: dotnetnuke-6

I have developed a project in dnn 6.2 which is run good in local
 server. But while i am doing live, it's not showing current project
 but showing dnn default project (the default theme of dnn project
 which come free with dnn ).So any one have an idea what kind of
 setting i have to change while doing project live.

Comment: refer to Nuke manuals first or check their site

Comment: I am not getting suitable answer from their blog that's why i posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi I have done this. 
1- Copy file system with local dnn to web server
2- Restore dnn database to database server accessible to web server 
3- Update PortalAlias table with webserver domain name 
4- Update connection string(s) in web.confg to new database location.**